# Is this indirect passive or potential?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, potential-form

[image]

> 「第三級冒険者」と明確な地位を**認められる**のもLv.2からだ。Lv.1が平均的であるなら、そこから先は少なからず才能と素質を**求められる**世界ということになる。

I'm not sure whether to interpret the two verbs as passive or potential. If it's passive what is the agent of the verbs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they are a usage as passive. I think the agent of 明確な地位を認められる is オラリオというゲーム or オラリオの冒険者達 and the agent of 才能と素質を求められる is オラリオというゲーム.

Comment: Just so you're aware, it is possible to edit and undelete your own answer rather than needing to create a new one.

Comment: Do you know my delete one? Can you see my delete one? I don't know that well but next I try it.

Comment: People with 2k rep (10k on fully graduated sites) can see deleted posts.

Comment: I understood. I don't arrive there yet now.